# Announcing the Close Vote Café

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, chat

### Backdrop

We get a ***lot*** of questions where the OP leaves much to be desired in terms of further information or clarification. In the hope that the OP gets back with further information the question will invariably get pushed back and forgotten.

This tendency drives up the number of low-quality, unanswered questions, which adversely affects a couple of our [metrics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair).

---

The [Close Vote Café](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32897/close-vote-cafe) is a chat room designed to help us get rid of questions that should be consigned to the SE graveyard. The chat room serves several purposes:

- users can post up existing, ageing questions that seem ripe for closure due to lack of clarity, information, objectiveness or relevance to the site. This will help

  - draw attention to ageing questions that should really be closed
  - foster discussion on questions that may be sitting "on the fence"
- lest they be forgotten, users can post links to new questions where they feel that more time should be provided for the OP to get back.
- users who have exhausted their close votes for the day can continue to post questions they deem closable by others. In essence, it's a buffered close review queue that can be revisited later.